# How to submit extra values in listbox c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I've got a question, and I can't find an answer to it. First off all, I'm a noob in programming, so all constructive feedback is of course welcome.

We are working on a program in c#. In a listbox, I've put objects (rectangles). The paramaters (well, only the color, as the height and width is fixed) of these rectangle's are saved into a database. But I want to give each object in the listbox an extra value (to be precise, I want to give the id of the object in the database). So that later on, I can get the ID of the selected item in the listbox. Is this possible?

```
 //########## TOEVOEGEN VAN KLEUR AAN LISTBOX MET KLEURTJES + INITIALISATIE
        var queryKLeurenInDatabase = (from kleurtjes in dbo.tblKleurs
                                      select kleurtjes);
        foreach (var item in queryKLeurenInDatabase)
        {
            int red, green, blue,ID;
            Rectangle kleurBox = new Rectangle();
            kleurBox.Height = 18;
            kleurBox.Width = 160;
            red = item.Red.Value;
            green = item.Green.Value;
            blue = item.Blue.Value;
            ID = item.KleurID;
            kleurBox.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { R = Convert.ToByte(red), G = Convert.ToByte(green), B = Convert.ToByte(blue), A = 255 });
            ListItem dataItem = new ListItem();
            dataItem.Tag = ID;                
            listBoxOpgeslagenKleuren.Items.Add(kleurBox);
            //ListItem dataItem = new ListItem();
            //dataItem.Text = "value to show";
            //dataItem.Value = *another value you want *;
            //listBox.Items.Add(dataItem);
        }
```

Comment: Create a data class and specify the listbox items, such as ID, Name, Description etc and bind the data to Database

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the edits on my initial post. Works fine now.

Comment: Good. Keep coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the commenter, the solution is to create you own class, something like this:

```
public class DataItem { 

    public Rectangle Rect { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }

}
```

than you can create a `List<DataItem> listToBind` and bind it to your ListBox